# Laravel Vue.js Exactly the same code shows blank page when moved from dev to prod

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.6

I have built a Larvel 5.6 Vue.js app on Mac OS.  The Vue.js app runs fine on Mac.  But when i copy it over to Ubuntu 16.04 vue.js piece doesn't run anymore.  I see a blank page.  I have reinstalled node_modules and ofcourse rebuilt the vue.js code with npm.

Comment: We're going to need a bit more to go on here. There's many reasons why this might happen e.g. your server might not be serving resources correctly or somethng else might be happening. Any errors in the console or the logs ?

Comment: No errors at all.  just the blank page.  Laravel runs fine.  Its the Vue.js part.

Comment: If you navigate to the page that the browser tries to get the JS from does it show anything?

Comment: Check storage/logs

Comment: @apokryfos - no nothing shows.  It just goes to the blank state.   I can see title of the welcome page for laravel but nothing beyond that.

Comment: Make sure your server is configured to serve the scripts in public properly. It does not seem to be the case right now

Comment: @aprkryfos - it is configured to do so.

Comment: Strange but worked without any effort except moving from a sub domain to the main domain.